# 100-line Tensorflow code and Keras equivalent do not produce the same result, Tensorflow result does not converge, why?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, generative-adversarial-network

I am more used to Keras than Tensorflow but would like to switch to Tensorflow as it seems more powerful.

I am doing experiments with a basic GAN, the code of which is provided for both TF (I use version 1.15.2) and Keras (2.2.5), below.
The GAN learns to generate 2D points fitting a 2D curve, f(x) = x^2. Every point is considered as a 2D vector 'individual', (x,y).

The following 2 python programs compile and run out-of-the-box, and produce exactly the same result. However, the TF version does not converge properly at all.

I tried everything I could to understand what's going wrong, to no avail. Obviously, there is something that I miss.

The TF version is largely inspired from the official GAN tutorial located here: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/dcgan

I also provide the code in 2 pastebin links:

Keras version: https://pastebin.com/N26e3hWh
Tensorflow version: https://pastebin.com/9ebmSyJB

Keras version:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import hstack
from numpy import zeros
from numpy import ones
from numpy.random import rand
from numpy.random import randn
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import keras.backend as K
from matplotlib import pyplot

class GanPointGraph_Keras(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.latent_dim = 5
        self.discriminator = self.define_discriminator()
        self.generator = self.define_generator(self.latent_dim)
        self.gan_model = self.define_gan(self.generator, self.discriminator)

    def define_discriminator(self, n_inputs=2):
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Dense(25, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', input_dim=n_inputs))
        model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
        model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
        print(K.eval(model.optimizer.lr))
        return model

    def define_generator(self, latent_dim, n_outputs=2):
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Dense(15, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', input_dim=latent_dim))
        model.add(Dense(n_outputs, activation='linear'))
        return model

    def define_gan(self, generator, discriminator):
        discriminator.trainable = False
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(generator)
        model.add(discriminator)
        model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
        return model

    def generate_latent_points(self, n):
        x_input = randn(self.latent_dim * n)
        x_input = x_input.reshape(n, self.latent_dim)
        return x_input

    def generate_fake_samples(self, n):
        x_input = self.generate_latent_points(n)
        X = self.generator.predict(x_input)
        return X

    def generate_real_samples(self, n):
        X1 = rand(n) - 0.5
        X2 = X1 * X1
        X1 = X1.reshape(n, 1)
        X2 = X2.reshape(n, 1)
        X = hstack((X1, X2))    
        return X

    def train(self):
        n_batch = 128
        half_batch = int(n_batch / 2)
        x_real = self.generate_real_samples(half_batch)
        y_real = ones((half_batch, 1))
        x_fake = self.generate_fake_samples(half_batch)
        y_fake = zeros((half_batch, 1))
        self.discriminator.train_on_batch(x_real, y_real)
        self.discriminator.train_on_batch(x_fake, y_fake)
        x_gan = self.generate_latent_points(n_batch)
        y_gan = ones((n_batch, 1))
        self.gan_model.train_on_batch(x_gan, y_gan)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    g = GanPointGraph_Keras();

    for epoch in range(10000):
        print('Epoch', epoch)
        g.train()
        if epoch % 1000 == 0:
            g_objects = g.generate_fake_samples(100)
            r_objects = g.generate_real_samples(100)

            pyplot.clf()
            pyplot.title('Keras iteration ' + str(epoch))
            pyplot.scatter([i[0] for i in r_objects], [i[1] for i in r_objects], c='black')
            pyplot.scatter([i[0] for i in g_objects], [i[1] for i in g_objects], c='red')
            pyplot.show()
```

Tensorflow version:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution() # if using TF 1.15.x
from tensorflow.keras import layers

import numpy as np
from numpy.random import rand
from numpy import hstack

from matplotlib import pyplot

class GanPointGraph(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.latent_dim = 5
        self.generator = self.make_generator()
        self.discriminator = self.make_discriminator()

        self.cross_entropy = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True)        
        self.generator_optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
        self.discriminator_optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)

    def make_generator(self):
        model = tf.keras.Sequential()
        model.add(layers.Dense(15, activation='relu', input_dim=self.latent_dim))
        model.add(layers.Dense(2))
        return model

    def make_discriminator(self):
        model = tf.keras.Sequential()
        model.add(layers.Dense(25, activation='relu', input_dim=2))
        model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')) # (-infinity, infinity) -> (0, 1)
        return model

    def generator_loss(self, fake_output):
        #return self.cross_entropy(tf.ones_like(fake_output), fake_output)
        return tf.reduce_mean(tf.math.log(1-fake_output))

    def discriminator_loss(self, real_output, fake_output):
        #real_loss = self.cross_entropy(tf.ones_like(real_output), real_output)
        #fake_loss = self.cross_entropy(tf.zeros_like(fake_output), fake_output)
        #total_loss = real_loss + fake_loss
        #return total_loss
        loss_real = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.math.log(real_output))
        loss_fake = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.math.log(1-fake_output))
        D_loss = loss_real + loss_fake
        return D_loss

    def generate_real_samples(self, n):
        X1 = rand(n) - 0.5
        X2 = X1 * X1
        X1 = X1.reshape(n, 1)
        X2 = X2.reshape(n, 1)
        x_train = hstack((X1, X2))
        return x_train

    def generate_fake_samples(self, n):
        z_sample = np.random.normal(0, 1.0, size=[n, self.latent_dim]).astype(np.float32)
        return self.generator(z_sample, training=False).numpy()

    def train(self):
        images = self.generate_real_samples(128);
        noise = tf.random.normal([images.shape[0], self.latent_dim])

        with tf.GradientTape() as gen_tape, tf.GradientTape() as disc_tape:
            generated_images = self.generator(noise, training=True)

            real_output = self.discriminator(images, training=True)
            fake_output = self.discriminator(generated_images, training=True)

            gen_loss = self.generator_loss(fake_output)
            disc_loss = self.discriminator_loss(real_output, fake_output)

        gradients_of_generator = gen_tape.gradient(gen_loss, self.generator.trainable_variables)
        gradients_of_discriminator = disc_tape.gradient(disc_loss, self.discriminator.trainable_variables)

        self.generator_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients_of_generator, self.generator.trainable_variables))
        self.discriminator_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients_of_discriminator, self.discriminator.trainable_variables))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    g = GanPointGraph();

    for epoch in range(10000):
        print('Epoch', epoch)
        g.train()
        if epoch % 1000 == 0:
            g_objects = g.generate_fake_samples(100)
            r_objects = g.generate_real_samples(100)

            pyplot.clf()
            pyplot.title('Tensorflow iteration ' + str(epoch))
            pyplot.scatter([i[0] for i in r_objects], [i[1] for i in r_objects], c='black')
            pyplot.scatter([i[0] for i in g_objects], [i[1] for i in g_objects], c='red')
            pyplot.show()
```

If you run the program, you will see that the Keras version converges quite reliably.
The TF version just "dances around" the solution, producing quite bad results very often, even after a high number of epochs.

What am I doing wrong in Tensorflow?

Thanks,

FC

Answer (score 0):

**Tensorflow** and **Keras** code wouldn't produce the **same** result, due to **randomizations**.
However, if the model is right and the **same** it should both **approach the same results** (in this case **Converging**).

I executed the code you provided in Google Colab Environment, both of the Codes you provided **converges** after `Epochs > 6000`.

Also if you want to port your **Native Keras Model** `import keras`, you could simply do this just by adding **Tensorflow before Keras** `import tensorflow.keras`, this is officially supported in **Tensorflow version > 2.0.0** (latest as of now 2.1.0).

**Modifying** the imports of your **Native Keras code**, you could run this in **TensorFlow 2.1.0**.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
```

You could read more about **TensorFlow Migration** in this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate).